# XSLT document() function to compare and combine two XML files

Tags: xpath, xslt, document

I am using Notepad++ and XSLT 1.0 to transform an XML file.
There is a Data.xml file and a Dict.xml file, and the latter holds translations of strings. I want the strings in Data.xml translated in the output.

Data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Textabschnitt>
        <Root ID="2050775654055586328">Administration</Root>
    </Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt ID="13667714361645396460">All</Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt ID="4765748458590838957">Application</Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt>
        <Tabelle>
            <Zelle>
                <Textabschnitt ID="14682159838120944212">Name</Textabschnitt>
            </Zelle>
            <Zelle>
                <Textabschnitt ID="2960145709916589219">Status</Textabschnitt>
            </Zelle>
        </Tabelle>
    </Textabschnitt>
</Root>
```

Dict.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DICT>
    <DICT_ENTRY LANG_ID="ro">
        <uicontrol id="2050775654055586328">Administrare</uicontrol>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
    <DICT_ENTRY LANG_ID="ro-RO">
        <uicontrol id="13667714361645396460">Toate</uicontrol>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
    <DICT_ENTRY LANG_ID="ro-RO">
        <uicontrol id="4765748458590838957">Aplicație</uicontrol>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
    <DICT_ENTRY LANG_ID="ro-RO">
        <uicontrol id="14682159838120944212">Nume</uicontrol>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
    <DICT_ENTRY LANG_ID="ro-RO">
        <uicontrol id="2960145709916589219">Stare</uicontrol>
    </DICT_ENTRY>
</DICT>
```

The output should be the same as Data.xml, but with the contents of the Textabschnitt elements replaced with the translations identified by the @id attribute.

I have looked at a lot of examples of document() usage, both online and in O'Reilly. However, I can't get it to read the file and output it.

The XSLT I have been trying (among many other attempts) is:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:param name="translatedStrings" select="document('Dict.xml')"/>


<!--Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- replace string with translated string, identified with ID (first attempt) -->
    <xsl:template match="//@ID">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="." />
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$translatedStrings/DICT/DICT_ENTRY/uicontrol[@id=$id][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This particular output produces a blank file, and it is the last `xsl:value-of` statement that is at fault, I think.

I am sure I am doing something very basic and wrong, but am not sure what. Any pointers to the right approach and syntax would be very gratefully received. Thank you.

Edit: for clarity, the output I would like is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Textabschnitt>
        <Root ID="2050775654055586328">Administrare</Root>
    </Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt ID="13667714361645396460">Toate</Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt ID="4765748458590838957">Aplicație</Textabschnitt>
    <Textabschnitt>
        <Tabelle>
            <Zelle>
                <Textabschnitt ID="14682159838120944212">Nume</Textabschnitt>
            </Zelle>
            <Zelle>
                <Textabschnitt ID="2960145709916589219">Stare</Textabschnitt>
            </Zelle>
        </Tabelle>
    </Textabschnitt>
</Root>
```

Comment: While your attempt does not produce the expected result, it should not produce a blank file either. I strongly suggest you test this in an environment that provides useful error messages.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Work computer, so I am limited in what they currently permit, but will continue to ask for a better tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Textabschnitt[@ID]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@ID" />
    <Textabschnitt ID="{$id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$translatedStrings/DICT/DICT_ENTRY/uicontrol[@id=$id]"/>
    </Textabschnitt>
</xsl:template>
```

BTW, if you're using XSLT 1.0, your stylesheet should not declare `version="2.0"`.

---

Edit:

If you want to translate not only the text of `Textabschnitt` but also of any of its descendants, then you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::Textabschnitt and @ID]/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../@ID" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$translatedStrings/DICT/DICT_ENTRY/uicontrol[@id=$id]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you @y.arazim. I have corrected the version number and the name of the file read, as well as your suggestion, but it still produces a blank file.

Comment: I have also tried: `<xsl:value-of select="document('Dict.xml')/DICT/DICT_ENTRY/uicontrol[@id=$id]"/>`

and
`<xsl:value-of select="document('Dict.xml')/DICT/DICT_ENTRY/uicontrol[1]"/>`
which still produce a blank output file. So I must be doing something more drastically wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that your processor does not allow access to external files?

Comment: Notepad++ v8.5, XML Tools plugin -> XSL Transformation. Can't find much documentation on it, but if it supports XSLT 1.0, it should support reading external files. I will try this if I can on another system. thanks for looking at this.